# Getting value of website Table by it's Width using webbrowser control VB.NET

Tags: html, vb.net

I have a question: Is it possible to get the text value of a Website table by it's Width in VB.NET using webbrowser control?
Why? Because the Table has a name (row_resultsTable_4), but the child columns has no name (they have the same name (txt_conteudo_lista tbl_line_border) and I only want to get a specific value of a column, and as the width it's always the same, I'm thinking if it's possible to get the value only by it's width.

For example, Get the width "200px" text value of table "row_resultsTable_4".

Is it possible? If yes, how?

To be honest, I'm really new in VB.NET don't know even where to start.
Any code snippets it's really appreciated.

I appreciate your time reading and helping me.

[image]

Comment: You can use `GetElementsByTagName("TABLE")`, use a `Where()` clause to filter an HtmlElement with a specific name, get its Children collection, loop this collection until you find a child element with Tag `TD` and a `width` Attribute that matches the measure you seek. Get its Value or InnerHtml. -- Or, pass the HTML content to [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) and retrieve those nodes specifying the path.

Comment: Hello @Jimi thanks a lot for your explanation but I kinda had a brain freeze right now haha I'm really noob here. Can you give me a snippet or something? I know it's asking a lot but I really need it :/ Thanks again for your time

Comment: Maybe. If you provide a sample HTML, from the opening `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the closing `</html>`.

Comment: @Jimi The page: https://www.filemail.com/d/qqyzwmesuojrahc 
and here is the picture explaining https://i.ibb.co/2hd3tLY/exampletest.png

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working.

```
Dim resultsTable As HtmlElement = IEWebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("DgitaTable_resultsTable")
Dim resultRows As HtmlElementCollection = resultsTable.GetElementsByTagName("tr")
Dim aRow As HtmlElement = resultRows.Item(Int32.Parse(txtRow.Text) + 1)
Dim aColumn As HtmlElement = aRow.GetElementsByTagName("td").Item(Int32.Parse(txtColumn.Text) - 1)
txtOutput.Text = aColumn.InnerText
```